# Pass GET variable from URL to .js, and from the .js to .php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hi I currently have a JS file being called to populate my html page with dynamic data. My JS file calls a PHP file to fetch stuff from my sqldb and my PHP file echos json_encode the stuff it got from the sqldb, which in turn is used to populate the html page.

My problem is that depending on what's in the url ie ?user=Bob, I want my js file to call the php file to search for Bob. Right now it searches for current user if ?user=xxxx is not specified. It seems the $GET['user'] is always null, thus it's not being passed because I suspect the JS file working as a middleman. Here are my code snippets:

My URL:
www.website.com/index.php?user=Bob

My HTML Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/get-data.js"></script>
```

My JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'php/retrieve-db.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            var name = response[0];
            var location = response[1]; 

            $('#name').html(name);
            $('#location').val(location);
            }
    });
});
```

My PHP Code

```
$id;

if (isset($_GET["user"]))
{
    $id = $_GET["user"];
}
else
{
    $id = $_SESSION['loggedInUser'];
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE User = '$user'";
if($result = mysqli_query($sqlconnection,$query))
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

Comment: Careful, you've opened yourself up to SQL injection attacks.  Use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid this problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe you want to do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'php/retrieve-db.php',
        data: <?php echo json_encode($_GET); ?>,
        dataType: 'json',
....
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks @Brad and @Ashwin Musjija for pointing out. I was focusing on answer too quickly that I overlook the possible non persistent XSS attack.

Comment: -1 for introducing an XSS attack point into the code.  Always use `json_encode()` around data being inserted into JavaScript.  You also need to encode the data in the URL if you're doing it manually.

Comment: Why not just use the `data` attribute?

Comment: how $_GET['user'] fetched in js

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have corrected my answer to fix XSS possible attack based on @Brad suggestion.

Comment: and using data attribute as what @AshwinMukhija suggested.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still isn't working for me. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, which part it doesn't work? Did retrieve-db.php get $_GET data?

Comment: It did not get the $GET data, it said it was empty still.

Comment: Did you access your website with GET query. For example: www.yourwebsite.com/index.php?user=Bob

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you instead of using javascript from `js/get-data.js` and put your Javascript directly in your index.php. `<script> // ajax code here </script>`.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `data` attribute in your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: $("#myForm").serialize(), //for example. You can change this to something relevant.
    /*rest of the code*/
});
```

What this will do is prepare a GET request with the proper data, for example, `http://path/to/backend/?key1=value1&key2=value2`